# How to get all possible encodings in tokens with bpe tokenizer

Tags: python, encoding, tokenize

I am using a BPE tokenizer in Python to tokenize a set of words related to a similar topic. However, when using `bpe_tokenizer.encode("splace").tokens`, I systematically get `["spl", "ace"]` even though, after checking, `["s", "place"]` also works since "s" and "place" are both tokens.

How can I get all possible token encodings using my trained tokenizer and without manually iterating over all possible splits and all generated tokens?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] (incl. all imports).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.